# how to get value from spinctrl and send it to .exe file in python script

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, subprocess, wxwidgets

I am new to python and wxpython, I am making a automated tool using python and for user interface wxpython and i use shell script.shell script can be called from the python. but now I am facing problem with the spinctrl value. whenever that spinctrl value changes it have to send that value into one txt.exe file which is written in BASH .{  if we run txt.exe file in command line it will ask for number then it will accept that value whenever we press enter}. but i am not able to understand that how to send value from spinctrl to txt.exe whenever i press "ok" button in GUI. please share your thoughts and knowledge.
Thank you

Comment: It is hard to understand the concept. Can you show us your code and tell what did you try and why it did not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call an executable in Python, you need to look at Python's subprocess module: http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

If your exe doesn't accept arguments, then it won't work. If you created the exe yourself using something like PyInstaller or py2Exe, then you need to make it so your app can accept arguments. The simplest way is using sys.argv, but there are also the optparse and argparse libraries in Python as well.

Answer (score 0):

I do not get a good feeling about your concept.  It is hard to say, but I suspect you would benefit from talking with someone experienced about what you are trying to achieve and how it could best be done.

However, to get you started down your current path, I think you should take a look at wxExecute ( http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_processfunctions.html#wxexecute ).  This will allow you to run your txt.exe utility from inside your GUI.

wxExecute is a wxWidgets utility.  If you are working in python then there will be a more direct way to do this using a python utility - some-one else will have to advise on that.  I suggest you edit your question for clarity so a python expert can help you.